# React MUI text field label text color in focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

Here I want to change "First Name" to color red.

I did it like this

```
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="First name" variant="outlined"
      sx={{
        '& .Mui-focused':{
          color:'red'
        }
      }}
      />
```

Now not only the shrink label, but others also changed like this

[image]

How do change only the shrunk label color?
[This is my codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-herschel-d9n4n4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a 'label' keyword:

```
<TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="First name"
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
          "& label.Mui-focused": {
            color: "red"
          }
        }}
      />
```